# How do you update a parent class object (self.progress) inside a child thread?

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm trying to run a progress status bar to signal the user a task is being executed. I have tried different strategies without success.

In this code the problem is I can´t update, from a child thread, the value of the progress bar. I'm doing something wrong.

```
import time
import threading
from tkinter import Tk, Button
from tkinter.ttk import Progressbar

class App():
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.button = Button(root)
        self.button.grid(row=1,column=0, padx=2,pady=2);
        self._resetbutton()
        self.progress = Progressbar(root, length=330, mode = 'determinate') 
        self.progress.grid(  row=2,column=0, columnspan=4,padx=2,pady=2);    

    def _resetbutton(self):
        self.running = False
        self.button.config(text="Start", command=self.startthread)
    def startthread(self):
        self.running = True
        newthread = threading.Thread(target=self.status_bar)
        newthread.start()
        self.button.config(text="Stop", command=self._resetbutton)

        for  x in range(12):
                time.sleep(.75)
                print(".");

    def status_bar( self ): 
        value = 0;
        print("started thread");

        while self.running:           
            value = ( value + 10 ) % 100;    
            #self.progress['value'] = value;   # <-- failure
            
            time.sleep(0.5); 
            print( value );

        print("done thread");

ventana_principal=Tk()
calculadora=App(ventana_principal)
ventana_principal.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you can see the changes in the startthread function to make this progress bar work.

```
def startthread(self):
    def status_bar( ): 
        value = 0;
        print("started thread");

        while self.running:           
            value = ( value + 10 ) % 100;    
            self.progress['value'] = value;   # <-- failure
            
            time.sleep(0.5); 
            print( value );

        print("done thread");


    def aux_func( ): 
        while self.running:           
                time.sleep(.75)
                print(".");
   

    self.running = True
    newthread = threading.Thread(target=status_bar)
    newthread.start()
    newthread2 = threading.Thread(target=aux_func)
    newthread2.start()
    self.button.config(text="Stop", command=self._resetbutton)
```